# Shell script not working as intended

Tags: shell, tcsh

I'm having some issues with my shell script.  The first issue is if I type "No" or "n" for the when it prompts the user, I get an error says "No endif".  Do my 3 endif's not work in this case?

Also my for loop is supposed to check a file has changed, if it hasn't don't copy it, if it has copy it.  However my comparison isn't working and it is copying every file each time.

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

if (! -d backup ) then
    echo "The backup folder does not exist.  Would you like to create it?  Y for Yes N for No"
    set userAnswer=$<
    if ($userAnswer == "yes" || $userAnswer == "y"|| $userAnswer == "Y" || $userAnswer == "YES") then
        mkdir backup
        else if ($userAnswer == "no" || $userAnswer == "n"|| $userAnswer == "N" || $userAnswer == "NO") then
            echo "No directory created"
            else
                echo "Invalid response"
                exit 1
            endif
        endif
    endif
else
foreach i ( *.c )
    if ("$i" == "/backup/$i") then
        echo file has not changed
    else
        cp $i backup
        echo test
    endif
end
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of indented lines between the first line and the **else** statement about 13 lines further down. This block has one nested if/else if/else/endif statement, for which there should be only one endif:

```
if ($userAnswer == "yes" || $userAnswer == "y"|| $userAnswer == "Y" || $userAnswer == "YES") then
    mkdir backup
else if ($userAnswer == "no" || $userAnswer == "n"|| $userAnswer == "N" || $userAnswer == "NO") then
    echo "No directory created"
else
     echo "Invalid response"
     exit 1
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `switch` might simplify the code a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

if (! -d backup ) then
    echo "The backup folder does not exist.  Would you like to create it?  Y for Yes N for No"
    set userAnswer=$<
    switch ($userAnswer)
        case [yY][eE][sS]:
            echo "Answer was yes"
            breaksw
        case [yY]:
            echo "Answer was yes"
            breaksw
        case [nN][oO]:
            echo "Answer was no"
            breaksw
        case [nN]:
            echo "Answer was no"
            breaksw
     endsw
    # ....
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have 3 endif's you only need 1... (I think) sh FanBoy*